# How to make find() accept an array instead of one object?

Tags: jsdata, js-data-angular

Using JS-Data 2.6 in Angular, I'm trying to load an array of data using a nice clean URL, e.g. /report/22. (This format makes sense, because it's following business logic - I'm loading a report data by category id, and getting several rows back.)

However,

- when I use `find`, then js-data dies with the dreaded `[Error] "attrs" must be an object!` because it expects 1 row, and cannot be convinced otherwise - unless I'm missing something.
- when I use `findAll`, then I need to search using uglier `/report/?categoryId = 22` - and change the server
- when I use actions, then it appends action name to the URI, which I don't need, e.g. `/report/22/myaction`

Is there any way to use either find() or findAll() to

- have a clean URL
- load an array of data
- preferably, not changing the server implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in this answer assumes you're using the HTTP adapter.

JSData's default expecations are the following:

- `GET /<resource>/:id` returns an object, e.g. `{ id: 1 }`
- `GET /<resource>` returns an array of objects, e.g. `[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]`
- `POST /<resource>  { some: 'field' }` creates a single item in your database
  and returns the updated item, e.g. `{ id: 1, some: 'field' }`
- `PUT /<resource>/:id  { updated: 'field' }` updates a single item in your
  database and returns the updated item, e.g. `{ id: 1, updated: 'field' }`
- `PUT /<resource>  { updated: 'field' }` updates a collection of items in your
  database and returns the updated items, e.g. `[{ id: 1, updated: 'field' }, { id: 2, updated: 'field' }]`
  -`DELETE /<resource>/:id` deletes a single item from your database
- `DELETE /<resource>` deletes a collection of items from your database

By default, [`DS#find`](http://js-data.io/docs/dsfind) does
`GET /<resource>/:id`, and [`DS#findAll`](http://js-data.io/docs/dsfindall) does
`GET /<resource>`.

Any response from the server needs to be in the right format by the time it gets
to `DS#inject`.

The lifecycle for these calls is the following:

1. Call `find` or `findAll` method of adapter

   1. Call `GET` method of adapter
   2. Call `HTTP` method of adapter
   3. Call `deserialize` method on server response
2. Pass adapter response to the `afterFind` or `afterFindAll` hook
3. Check `cacheResponse`

   1. If `true`, pass result of `afterFind` or `afterFindAll` to `DS#inject`
   2. If `false`, pass result of `afterFind` or `afterFindAll` to `DS#createInstance`
4. Return final result

The only way to avoid an injection error is to either:

A) Not inject the adapter response into the datastore

or

B) Massage the data into the correct format before it is passed into `DS#inject`

`DS#inject` requires either an object that has a field specified by the
Resource's `idAttribute` option, or an array of the same.

You have three opportunities to massage the data before it gets to `DS#inject`:

1. An HTTP response interceptor
2. The `deserialize` hook
3. The `afterFind` or `afterFindAll` hook

In any one of those methods you could fix the data to be what `DS#inject`
expects.

If you want to be able to do `Report.find(22)` then you might do:

```
var Report = store.defineResource({
  name: 'report',
  afterFind: function (Report, data, cb) {
    cb(null, {
      id: 22,
      data: data
    });
  }
});

Report.find(22).then(function (report) {
  report.id; // 22
  report.data; // [{...}, {...}]
});
```

All of this assumes you really want to be able to use `DS#find`, but `DS#find`
and `DS#findAll` are meant to be used with RESTful resources where a Resource
corresponds to a table in a database and instances of the Resource correspond to
rows in the table. Generating reports is typically one of those things where
you're compiling data from disparate sources, doing aggregations, etc. It's
not as predictable (and hence, this question).

Here's another option:

```
var Report = store.defineResource({
  name: 'report',

  /* Static Class Methods */
  findByCategoryId: function (id) {
    // Use the adapter directly
    return Report.getAdapter('http').find(Report, id).then(function (data) {
      // Inject the result into the store
      return Report.inject({
        id: 22,
        data: data
      });
    });
  }
});

Report.findByCategoryId(22). then(function (report) {
  return Report.findByCategoryId(23);
}).then(function (report) {
  Report.filter(); // [{...}, {...}]
});
```

Basically, there are many ways to accomplish any particular task, each with its
own set of pros/cons. JSData can only generalize to so many use-cases with its
default settings.

To unlock the power of JSData and maximize your productivity, you'll want to
take note of the many options and hooks in JSData that allow you to mold JSData
to your liking. If you find that any particular extension or customization
you've written could be generalized and benefit a lot of others who have the
same use-case, [let us know](https://github.com/js-data/js-data/issues/new)!

Cheers!